# refer to another page

Tags: jquery, html

Please help to make it work. It always refers to the page with "404 Not Found".

[image]

```js
 function GoTo(){

        var input_1 = $("input[name='keyword']").val();
        var input_2 = $("input[name='location']").val();

        if(input_1 !== "" || input_2 !== "")
        {
            window.location.href = "page2.html";
        }
    }
```

```html
   <form method="post">
      
                <button class="btn search">Search</button>
    
    </form>
```

Comment: Just compare the expected URL (by opening the expected page) with the actual URL (by executing the function and looking at the location bar). What is the difference between these two? Tell us by [edit]ing your question.

Comment: Should you set the full url to location.href not just the filename?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Main problem is inside **base** tag that I've used in my page. Also I've changed my js code:

```js
<script>
    $('.search').click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
        window.location.href='./grid.html';
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

just add "/" at the beginning of your link so it will be relative to you root

```
window.location.href= "/page2.html"
```